# How does one pull a string from an array of strings and place it into its own array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to get a one dimensional array to equal a specific string from a two dimensional array of strings. I've attached my code and I cannot figure out how to properly use `strncpy` or `strcpy`. In my example, I'm trying to get `ColdestLake` to contain the name of the lake whose yearly average temperature is the coldest. I'm trying to pull this from the array of lake names, `Lakes[6][12]`. From the math, it should be Lake Superior, so I want "Superior" to become the value of `ColdestLake`. I am trying to complete the same task with `WarmestLake`. I have already written the correct code for displaying the temperature. I have attached a photo of the returned value (for this specific code)

[image: Here]

I appreciate the time, as I am new to C programming.

Update: Thank you everyone for the help! I am new to C (taking a university class), and unfortunately we learned while(!feof(file)) is what to use, and this is what I have been required to use for this particular project. I have updated my code to ensure that values are not undefined, and have defined 365 as Days. Please let me know if there is anything else I can improve. Thanks!

Code Below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <float.h>
#define Days 365

int main ()
{
    //Variable Declaration
    char Lakes[6][12] = {"Superior", "Michigan", "Huron", "Erie", "Ontario", "St. Claire"};
    char ColdestLake[12] = {""};
    char WarmestLake[12] = {""};
    char AboveAverageLakes[6][12] = {"","","","","",""};
    char BelowAverageLakes[6][12] = {"","","","","",""};
    double Sums[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    double Averages[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    double Superior[Days];
    double Michigan[Days];
    double Huron[Days];
    double Erie[Days];
    double Ontario[Days];
    double St_Claire[Days];
    double ColdestTemperature;
    double WarmestTemperature;
    FILE *input;
    int i;
    int j;
    int AboveAverageCount = 0;
    int BelowAverageCount = 0;

    //Initializing The Input Data File
    input = fopen("Lake Data.txt", "r");

    //Assigning Data From File To Array's Of Each Lake
    while (!feof(input))
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
        {
            fscanf(input, "%*lf %*lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", &Superior[i], &Michigan[i], &Huron[i], &Erie[i], &Ontario[i], &St_Claire[i]);
        }
    }

    //Getting Sum Of Each Lake's Temperature
    for (i = 0; i < Days; i++)
    {
        Sums[0] += Superior[i];
        Sums[1] += Michigan[i];
        Sums[2] += Huron[i];
        Sums[3] += Erie[i];
        Sums[4] += Ontario[i];
        Sums[5] += St_Claire[i];

        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            Sums[6] += Sums[j];
        }
    }

    //Getting Average Of Each Lake's Temperature
    Averages[0] = Sums[0]/Days;
    Averages[1] = Sums[1]/Days;
    Averages[2] = Sums[2]/Days;
    Averages[3] = Sums[3]/Days;
    Averages[4] = Sums[4]/Days;
    Averages[5] = Sums[5]/Days;

    //Getting Average Of All Lakes
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Averages[6] += Averages[i]/6;
    }

    //Printing Average Of Each Lake's Temperature
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("The Average For Lake %s Was %.2lf Degrees Celsius.\n",Lakes[i], Averages[i]);
    }


    //Printing The Average Of All The Lakes
    printf("\nThe Average Of All The Lakes Was %.2lf Degrees Celsius.\n", Averages[6]);

    //Calculating Warmest And Coldest Lakes
    ColdestTemperature = DBL_MAX;
    WarmestTemperature = DBL_MIN;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        //Getting Coldest Temperature & Lake
        if (Averages[i] < ColdestTemperature)
        {
            ColdestTemperature = Averages[i];
            strcpy(ColdestLake, Lakes[i]);
        }

        //Getting Warmest Temperature & Lake
        if (Averages[i] > WarmestTemperature)
        {
            WarmestTemperature = Averages[i];
            strncpy(WarmestLake, Lakes[i], 12);
        }

        //Counting Lakes Above Average Temperature
        if (Averages[i] > Averages[6])
        {
            AboveAverageCount++;
            strncpy(AboveAverageLakes[i], Lakes[i], 12);
        }

        //Counting Lakes Below Average Temperature
        if (Averages[i] < Averages[6])
        {
            BelowAverageCount++;
            strncpy(BelowAverageLakes[i], Lakes[i], 12);
        }
    }

    //Printing Warmest And Coldest Lakes
    printf("\nThe Coldest Lake Was %s With A Temperature Of %.2lf Degrees Celsius.\n", ColdestLake, ColdestTemperature);
    printf("The Warmest Lake Was %s With A Temperature Of %.2lf Degrees Celsius.\n", WarmestLake, WarmestTemperature);

    //Printing How Many Lakes Are Below Average Temperature
    printf("\nThere Are %d Lakes Below The Average Of All The Lakes. They Are:\n", BelowAverageCount);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(BelowAverageLakes[i],"") == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        printf("Lake %s\n", BelowAverageLakes[i]);
    }

    //Printing How Many Lakes Are Above Average Temperature
    printf("\nThere Are %d Lakes Above The Average Of All The Lakes. They Are:\n", AboveAverageCount);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(AboveAverageLakes[i],"") == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        printf("Lake %s\n", AboveAverageLakes[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please replace the image of your output with the output itself, copy-and-pasted as plain text and formatted as code.

Comment: BTW, I haven't looked closely at your code but `strncpy` is almost certainly not what you want to use. https://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html

Comment: Why not `int coldindex, warmindex; for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { if (Averages[i] < ColdestTemperature) { ColdestTemperature = Averages[i]; coldindex = i } .. /* same for warm */ }` then you have the index of the warmest and coldest, so your answers are simply `lakes[coldindex]` and `lakes[warmindex]`.

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
Sums[0] += Superior[i];
```

and similar statements...

The array `Sums[]` has not been initialized so this is using uninitialized values as 'source' in a math statement.  This results in undefined behavior.

Suggest changing:

```
double Sums[7],...
```

to:

```
double Sums[7] = {0}, ...
```

OT: for ease of readability and understanding: please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

the posted code contains the 'magic' number 365.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` or `enum` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Please read: [why while(!feof( file ) ) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

regarding:

```
Averages[6] += Averages[i]/6;
```

This is using a source of `Averages[6]`  However that value is never initialized, resulting in undefined behavior.  Suggest changing:

```
 ..., Averages[7],
```

to:

```
 ..., Averages[7] = {0},
```

regarding:

```
ColdestTemperature = Averages[0];
WarmestTemperature = Averages[0];

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (Averages[i] < ColdestTemperature)
    {
        ColdestTemperature = Averages[i];
        strcpy(ColdestLake, Lakes[i]);
    }
```

The above will never update the `ColdestLake` with "Superior" because Averages will never be less than the initial value of `ColdestTemperature`  Similar considerations for the calculation of the `WarmestTemperature`.

Suggest replacing:

```
ColdestTemperature = Averages[0];
WarmestTemperature = Averages[0];
```

with:

```
ColdestTemperature = DBL_MAX;
WarmestTemperature = DBL_MIN;
```

as defined in the header file: `limits.h`

Answer (score 0):

If the coldest lake is Lake Superior, the test `if (Averages[i] < ColdestTemperature)` will not be true, because you initialized `ColdestTemperature` to `Averages[0]`. The simple solution is to also initialize `ColdestLake` to `Lakes[0]`. And do similarly for `WarmestLake`.

And once you've done this, there's no need to check `Averages[0]` in the loop, so you can start the loop at `i = 1`.

```
    //Calculating Warmest And Coldest Lakes
    ColdestTemperature = Averages[0];
    strcpy(ColdestLake, Lakes[0]);
    WarmestTemperature = Averages[0];
    strcpy(WarmestLake, Lakes[0]);

    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (Averages[i] < ColdestTemperature)
        {
            ColdestTemperature = Averages[i];
            strcpy(ColdestLake, Lakes[i]);
        }

        if (Averages[i] > WarmestTemperature)
        {
            WarmestTemperature = Averages[i];
            strcpy(WarmestLake, Lakes[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar suggests, the coldestlake is not true because you copyed the *first* value (which happens to be the coldest) in,so the if cause is never reached,aside from copying the string in first,you can do something like this.

```
#define INF 0x3f3f3f3f
    ...Your code...
    ColdestTemperature = INF;
    WarmestTemperature = -INF;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (Averages[i] < ColdestTemperature)
        {
            ColdestTemperature = Averages[i];
            strcpy(ColdestLake, Lakes[i]);
        }

        if (Averages[i] > WarmestTemperature)
        {
            WarmestTemperature = Averages[i];
            strcpy(WarmestLake, Lakes[i]);
        }
    }
```